# Emails not sending when calling multiple scripts

Tags: powershell, outlook, automation

Good afternoon - 
I have a "trigger file" that calls several scripts to run some morning reports.  Each called script contains code that attaches a file to an email and sends (via ComObject).  If I run each script individually then there all emails send correctly.  However, when i run the "trigger file", only a couple of the emails send and I am not receiving any error messages.  Any ideas what is happening?  I purposely made the trigger file run the scripts concurrently to save time.  But is that overloading Outlook?

**EDIT: Updated code to include Try/Catch block.  There are 8 scripts that run using this template.  All 8 successfully complete the excel open/run/save.  However, only some of the emails send.  And even with this Try/Catch block, no error message is being sent.**

```
#Establish script file locale
    $FullPath = “//fullpath/”
    $SavePath = “//savepath/”

#Open Excel file
& {
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $Excel.Visible=$False
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FullPath)

#Run Macro
    $app=$Excel.Application
    $app.Run("Macro1")

#Save and close Excel
    $Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts=$False
    $Workbook.SaveAs($SavePath,51)
    $Workbook.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()
}

#Send email with attachment
Try
{
    $EmailSettings=@{
        SMTPServer = "smtp"
        From = "me@email.com" 
        To = 
            @(
            "you@email.com"
            )
        Subject = "Subject"
        Attachments = $SavePath
        BodyAsHtml = $true
        Body =
            "<body><p>
            Attached is the thing.
            </b></p></body>"
    }
    Send-MailMessage @EmailSettings
}
Catch
{
$Subject = 'ERROR: '+$EmailSettings.Subject
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message+' '+$_.Exception.ItemName
Send-MailMessage -From me@email.com -To me@email.com -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer smtp -Body $ErrorMessage
}
```

Comment: Where is `$FullPath` defined? When creating COM objects, you should always clear memory afterwards by adding lines `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook)`, `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)` etc. followed by `[System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: Sorry, $FullPath and $SavePath are defined earlier in script but i eliminated a chunk for sake of brevity.  Would not having those clean-up lines impact the email delivery?  And would I also have to add them for the Outlook comobject created?

Comment: Why are using COM, vs just using Send-MailMessage? It is why that cmdlet exists. There should be little need for you to pop open heavy Outlook to do this.

Comment: @postanote - originally i was using Send-MailMessage, but because emails were not being delivered I assumed that perhaps there was a conflict/overload in sending that way.  I switched to COM as i thought it would force the creation of each email. Not the case though:(  Perhaps i'm sending or closing before it is ready?

Comment: You'll want to have error (try/catch) checking in place here to validate send before moving to new code block/execution.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far.  Added try/catch and moved to cmdlet and edited the post.  Still unable to identify what is preventing the emails from firing.